# statsmodel - TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'

Tags: python, forecasting, statmodels

I'm working on some forecasts using statsmodels' arima model.
This used to work well with

```
model_result = model.fit(disp = -1)
```

but it seems that disp no longer seems to be working -

https://github.com/biolab/orange3-timeseries/blob/a9fb2ab04dffdc8c17cb4020e94a93538099c285/orangecontrib/timeseries/models.py#L305-L306

Has anyone ran into the same problem and knows an alternative for disp?
It has not been possible for me to continue reasonably without this.

BR and thank you!

Comment: That link points to orange not statsmodels. There is no "shit" in statsmodels.

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same problem.
Two solutions:

1)Use an older version of statsmodels, where disp is still supported, you can do so by installing 0.12.2 version of statsmodels.
`$pip install statsmodels==0.12.2`
disp is an optional argument. If disp = True, or disp >0 convergence information is printed.
If disp = False or disp < 0 means no output in this case.
You can get rid of the warnings by using this in your code:

`import warnings`

`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`

2)Use the newer version of statsmodels. disp is no longer supported. So, you can not set a value.
use the following code:

`import statsmodels.api as smapi`

`model = smapi.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train_data, order=(1,1,2))`

`result = model.fit()`

Personally speaking the updated version of statsmodels is better.

Comment: Hi I don't think disp is a parameter in 0.12.2 version of statsmodels