# Stats Model - TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'

Tags: python, data-science, forecasting, arima, sarimax

I'm getting error while implementing model.fit(dis=0). Please help me on this. How to get rid of this error? I'm doing time series and forecasting for Electricity Board in USA PJMW.

```
ar_preds = []

history = [x for x in train_series]

for t in range(len(test_series)):

 model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
output = model_fit.forecast()
ar_preds.append(output[0][0])
history.append(test_series[t])

ar_pred_series = pd.Series(ar_preds, index=test_series.index)

error = mean_squared_error(test_series, ar_pred_series)

print('MSE: %.3f' % error)

plt.plot(test_series, label='Observed Values')
plt.plot(ar_pred_series, color='blue', label='Forecasted Values')
plt.legend()
plt.title('AR(1) Model Forecasts')
plt.ylabel('Energy Consumption (MW)')
plt.show()



TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [64], in <cell line: 4>()
      4 for t in range(len(test_series)):
      5     model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,0,0))
----> 6     model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
      7     output = model_fit.forecast()
      8     ar_preds.append(output[0][0])

TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [statsmodel - TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'disp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70223523/statsmodel-typeerror-fit-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-disp)

Comment: This does not help me.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions given in the link @AlexK gave you ?